# What is the correct way to create a new instance of a object using the repository pattern?

Tags: c#, repository, design-patterns

I've been playing around with the repository pattern using c# and .net.

my question regards creating new instances of `someRepositoryObject`. All examples I've seen so far use something like this:

```
using(ISomeRepository someRepository = new SomeRepository().getRepository())
{
    IsomeRepositoryObject repObj = new someRepositoryObject();
}
```

Doesn't calling `new someRepositoryObject` remove the point of using interfaces in the first place? Would it better to do something like:

```
using(ISomeRepository someRepository = new SomeRepository().getRepository())
{
    IsomeRepositoryObject repObj = someRepository.NewsomeRepositoryObject();
}
```

So the repository itself returns a new instance of the required object and the calling code has no knowledge of the class being passed to it, just that it is of type `ISomeRepositoryObject`.

This is all new to me, so I might be missing something obvious!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why `new SomeRepository().getRepository()` instead of just `new SomeRepository()` or something like `RepositoryFactory.getSomeRepository()` or even `SomeRepository.getRepository()`?

Comment: Thinking about it, there isn't a reason! I was using getRepository to to pull in a web.config appsetting which was then used to return the correct repository type. This code could be added to the constructor of SomeRepository.

Comment: Actually, looking at the code, I was using .getSomeRepository() to return a IsomeRepository object. This is something I was playing with before my Christmas break - so just getting my head around it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I'm using the second way you described and let the repository create a new instance. The reason is - as you mentioned, too - that I'm trying to separate the implementations of the interfaces from the code that uses the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I would use IOC Containers to help.

[Ninject](http://ninject.org/) is a nice solution to this. For example, in my MVC program, all my controller need some Service:

```
public class SampleController: Controller {
    public SampleController(IService service) {}

}
```

the IService is injected by Ninject, only global.asax.cs need to acknowledge the concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

What you have just described is abstract factory pattern.
In case of repository it's better to use IoC container to create new objects. In this case you will not use new keyword at all and you will work with abstraction only.
[Repository by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)